# %.#s format specifier in printf statement in c

Tags: c, string, printf, format-specifiers

Please explain the output. What does `%.#s` in `printf()` mean?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){

    char *A="HELLO";
    printf("%.#s %.2s\n",A,A);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
#s HE
```

Comment: Perhaps the documentation on [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) will help explain it.

Comment: You get the output `#s` because your format is wrong. It needs a number after the dot, like `"%.2#s"`. Not that it matters anyway, since the string format doesn't have an alternate form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. `#` in `printf` format specifier means alternative form, but according to the standard, `#` is only used together with `o`, `a`, `A`, `x`, `X`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, `G`, not including `s`.

> #### C11 §7.21.6.1 *The `fprintf` function* Section 6
>
> `#` The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’. For `o` conversion, it increases
>   the precision, if and only if necessary, to force the first digit of the result to be a
>   zero (if the value and precision are both `0`, a single `0` is printed). For `x` (or `X`)
>   conversion, a nonzero result has `0x` (or `0X`) prefixed to it. For `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversions, the result of converting a floating-point number always
>   contains a decimal-point character, even if no digits follow it. (Normally, a decimal-point character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit follows it.) For `g` and `G` conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the result. For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.

For example, on my machine, output is different:  `%.0#s HE`

Comment: This is a good answer but it is not, in my opinion, precisely correct. Please see my answer. If I am wrong there, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

`%.1s` is used to print the first character of the string

`%.2s` is used to print the first  two characters of the string

`%.3s` is used to print the first  three characters of the string   and so on

where   **# : alternative form of the conversion is performed** is a **flag** which have an optional usage with the **format** parameter in `printf()` and `fprintf()` functions etc.

But as @Yu Hao said `#` is only used together with `o`, `a`, `A`, `x`, `X`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, `G`, not including `s`.

in your case `%.#s` usage is Wrong.

Example usage from reference given by @WhozCraig :

```
printf("Hexadecimal:\t%x %x %X %#x\n", 5, 10, 10, 6);
printf("Octal:\t%o %#o %#o\n", 10, 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Yu Hao's answer that it is undefined behavior, but I think the reason is different. Yes, the `#` character works as a flag to convert the result to an alternative format. Yes, the `#` flag is undefined for strings. But in this case, the `#` is not a flag, it's a precision. It's still undefined, but the reason is different

The C11 standard at §6.21.6.1 says that the `%` sign is followed **in sequence** by:

1. Zero or more *flags* (including `#`)
2. An optional minimum *field width*
3. An optional *precision*
4. An optional *length modifier*
5. A *conversion specifier* character

Except for the conversion specifier, these are all optional. But the order in which they appear is always as above. So flag, if present, has to be first, immediately after the `%` character. Here what follows the `%` is not something indicating a flag, it is a period: `%.`, indicating precision.

When you have `%.#` in your format string for `printf()`, the period indicates that the following character is the precision for the conversion specification that follows. I.e., the `#` in your code specifies the *precision* for the string `s`, not a *flag*. To be a flag, it would have to directly follow the `%` character, without the intervening period.

With regard to precision, the C standard §7.21.6.1 says this:

```
The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed either by an asterisk * 
(described later) or by an optional decimal integer; if only the period is specified,
the precision is taken as zero. If a precision appears with any other conversion 
specifier, the behavior is undefined.
```

Since in your format string you have `%.#s`, and `#` is neither `an asterisk *` nor a `decimal integer`, the result is undefined.

So to be extremely exact about why your code is undefined, I think it's because the `#` character appears in place of a legal precision, not because it is an illegal flag for the `%s` conversion. It would be illegal as a flag, of course, but that's not what is precisely (har har) happening here.